# Return only the column 2 of a Text File - JAVA

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I have a text file with the following structure:

```
Col_A           Col_B            Col_C
  1               2                 3
  1               2                 3
  1               2                 3
```

I want to obtain only the second column. The result should be:

```
2
2
2
```

I have the following code, but it gives me only the first line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/cloudera/Downloads/sms-call-internet-tn-2013-12-31.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();
String[] columns = line.split("/t");
String valueNeeded = columns[0];
System.out.println(valueNeeded);
```

How can I achieve that?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop to read all lines :

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/cloudera/Downloads/sms-call-internet-tn-2013-12-31.txt"));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] columns = line.split("/t");
            String valueNeeded = columns[1];
            System.out.println(valueNeeded);

        }
```

Comment: Hi Berger, thanks for your response. Your code runs cool but I only want to return the second column...

Comment: @SaCvP : oh yes, just use the index 1 of the array instead of 0, I edited the answer.

Comment: It gives me the following error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Unix_TimeStamp.main(Unix_TimeStamp.java:14)